# ng-repeats, showing record while it's value is a part of field of another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got objects 'ing' with a field named 'id' and another one called 'fObj' with a field named 'contain'.

By using ng-repeat i'd like to show only these 'ing' objects where ing.id is a part of fObj.contain

e.g.

```
ing=[{id: 1,field: value},{id:2, field: othervalue},{id:3, field: cat}];
fObj={field1: value1, field: value2, contain: ':1:3:'};
```

By having this contain value I'd like to show only ing's with id=1 and id=3

Yeah, I know there are two types of data (number and string) but even if i changed numbers to strings it still didn't work

I just dont't know how to make it works. It's probably some kind of custom filter, but I've tried couples and nothing happend.

I would be glad if you suggest me a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller,

```
var ids = fObj.contain.split(':');
// the array for your ng-repeat
var displayIng = [];

// loop the objects, see if the id exists in the list of id's 
// retrieved from the split
for(i = 0; i < ing.length; i++) {
    if(ids.indexOf(ing.id.toString()) displayIng.push(ing[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split the numbers out of `fObj.contain;` and use them as hashmap object keys for simple filtering of the array

```js
var ing=[{id: 1},{id:2},{id:3}];
var fObj={contain: ':1:3:'};


var IDs = fObj.contain.split(':').reduce(function(a,c){
  a[c]=true;
  return a;
},{});
// produces {1:true,3:true}
    
var filtered = ing.filter(function(item){
  return IDs[item.id];
});
console.log(filtered)
```